# kineticJS: get the layer that is on top of other layers

Tags: kineticjs

I have a stage that contains multiple layers overlapping. How do I get the layer that is on top? Can I use the method `getAbsoluteZIndex()` without knowing the Z-index of any of them, since each of them is called using a button whenever the user wants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stage.children[stage.children.length - 1]
```